# How can I convert a QImage of format RGB32 to OpenCV::mat?

Tags: qt, opencv, qimage

I have a QImage of format RGB32
When I do this:

```
cv::Mat depthMat(depthImg.height(),depthImg.width(),CV_8UC3,(uchar*)depthImg.bits(),depthImg.bytesPerLine());
```

I get the image of the left. I am actually supposed to get the image on the right.
[image]

Comment: can't you convert your QImage from RGB32 to RGB888 ? This code should work with that king of format... or try to use CV_32SC3 instead of CV_8UC3 (not sure about that...)

Comment: Nope! Converting from RGB32 to RGB888 changes the colors!

Comment: @Poko And, using CV_32SC3 also doesn't work!

Comment: ok. sorry. I'm glad you solved it.

Answer (score 5):

Okay! I figured it out! RGB32 has 8 bits of R, 8 bits of G, 8 bits of B and 8 bits of Alpha. It's essentially RGBA. So, we can use this:

```
cv::Mat depthMat(depthImg.height(),depthImg.width(),CV_8UC4,(uchar*)depthImg.bits(),depthImg.bytesPerLine());
```

[image]